# Ctrl Alt T no longer opens terminal

Tags: command-line, 14.04

I wanted to change my computer name so I edited `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` and restarted.

Ever since then, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> no longer opens Terminal. I tried going into Keyboard and making a custom shortcut, but it still won't open Terminal. What gives?

Comment: Can you start it from the menu? What desktop environment are you using? Can you log in from TTY?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 14.04 in VirtualBox on a Windows 7 64-bit OS. I can start Terminal if I open the search, type terminal, and click the icon. I don't know what TTY is (I am a newb who just started using Ubuntu tonight)

Comment: Weird, if I change it to like Ctrl Alt G (or anything else really), it works, but if I change it to Ctrl Alt T, it doesn't?

Comment: Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140497/virtualbox-guests-no-longer-getting-shortcuts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reinstalled Ubuntu, now it works

Comment: OMG, the brute force way o_O